# I am not able to get the file path

Tags: java, selenium

I have created Script for Read data from excel file, but it gives me error like "C:\testdata.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)".
Please Hple.
This is my code.

```
 FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File ("C:\\testdata.xls")); 
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
 HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 String heading = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
 String searchText1 = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
 String searchText2 = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
 System.out.println("Heading is:" + heading);
 System.out.println("Search Text 1 is:" + searchText1);
 System.out.println("Search Text 2 is:" + searchText2);
 file.close();
```

Comment: Why the quadruple-backslashes? Did you try `c:\\testdata.xls` ?

Comment: Yes i have try  c://testdata.xls then also it give same error.

Comment: in run paste "c:\\testdata.xls" and run if it opens successfully...then your path is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify if the path is correct or not by creating file as

`new File ("C:\\testdata.xls")`

Then print the absolute path. Check if it is a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to be more specific. I'd imagine your file is in a subdirectory of C. 
If it is in a subdirectory include the hold path to the file.
For example,
"C:\Users\nicky\Desktop\MyProgram\file.txt" (double backslashes)

Or you could just copy the file into your project folder and call it by its name.
"file.txt"

Answer (score 0):

My file path is correct but my file extension is wrong.